# Is jQuery allowed in Chrome Exentsion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have the following for my extension. Do I need to declare permissions? The "code:" line is not working in my background file.

Background File:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // No tabs or host permissions needed!
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: '$("body").hide();'
  });
});
```

Manifest File:

```
{
  "name": "5 Stars!",
  "description": "5 Stars and Kudos!",
  "version": "2.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery.min.js", "background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "5 Stars!",
    "default_icon": "star.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Updated and included screenshot of current code:
[image: Current Code]

Answer (score 1):

Changing the order of your scripts field as `"scripts": ["jquery.min.js", "background.js"]` should solve your problem.

Comment: I am receiving the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.

Comment: I tried running your exact code with the change I mentioned, and it works. Have you added your `jquery.min.js` file to your extension folder? Try removing the mobile and ui version of jquery. Also download the latest version of jquery from the website. For me the version `jquery-3.2.1.min.js` gives no error in your code.

Comment: I downloaded the compressed, production jQuery 3.2.1 and updated 
 "scripts": ["jquery.min.js", "background.js"]

Comment: In that case it should be "scripts": ["jquery-3.2.1.min.js", "background.js"], or whatever your exact jquery filename is.

Comment: I noticed when using the Chrome console: jQuery('body').hide(); works and $ does not. However neither works with my extension, attached to the original post is a screenshot of what I currently have.

Comment: Like I said, the extension works with the same code for me. Check again whether your extension folder has your jquery file, and that the name matches exactly with the field in your "scripts" array.

Comment: Nothing I try seems to work, updated file names, etc. Maybe I'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your JQuery in your `manifest`:

```
"background":
{
    "scripts": ["jqueryLink.js", "file.js"]
}
```